# Is there a way to eliminate the association attribute in the HasManyGetAssociationsMixin (Sequelize)

Tags: typescript, sequelize.js, sequelize-typescript

I have two models in sequelize: coffees and tags. They have a many to many relationship through a coffee_tags table. I am using the special mixin HasManyGetAssociationsMixin to retrieve the tags corresponding to a coffee, but when I do so, it also adds an attribute with the relation. coffe.getTags() returns:

```
{
        "id": 2,
        "name": "Light Roast",
        "operatorId": 1,
        "iconUrl": "iconUrl",
        "shortName": "LR",
        "createdAt": "2023-10-03T17:44:50.080Z",
        "updatedAt": "2023-10-03T17:44:50.080Z",
        "CoffeeTag": {
            "id": 12,
            "tagId": 2,
            "coffeeId": 1,
            "createdAt": "2023-10-03T17:57:36.083Z",
            "updatedAt": "2023-10-03T17:57:36.083Z"
        }
    },
```

The special mixin BelongsToManyGetAssociationsMixin has an option joinTableAttributes, which also work for this mixin, but since I am using typescript it throws error because it isn´t declared as an option. If I did coffee.getTags({ joinTableAttributes: [] }), it would return:

```
{
        "id": 2,
        "name": "Light Roast",
        "operatorId": 1,
        "iconUrl": "iconUrl",
        "shortName": "LR",
        "createdAt": "2023-10-03T17:44:50.080Z",
        "updatedAt": "2023-10-03T17:44:50.080Z",
},
```

which is what I would like. Is there a way to do this with typescript?